# Grep don't working with special characters

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want Egrep this, from a file:

```
egrep "check (hello)"
```

but Egrep are not working, because "()". How to proceed?

Comment: try using \\( and \\)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fgrep`](http://ss64.com/bash/fgrep.html), not [`egrep`](http://ss64.com/bash/egrep.html), if you don't want characters to have special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape them:

```
egrep "check \(hello\)"
```